# How to insert a node with a value, depending on whether it exists or not

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a user registration with Authentication, but in turn, I insert these registrations in a collection of Firebase Realtime Database.

The structure of the database is as follows:

[image: database structure]

viewmodel of my register screen:

```
class RegisterViewModel : ViewModel() {

var email = mutableStateOf("")
var userName = mutableStateOf("")
var password = mutableStateOf("")
var status = mutableStateOf("1")

val state = mutableStateOf(RegisterState())

val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
val loginPresenter = AuthPresenter()


fun registrar(email: String, password: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {

        state.value = state.value.copy(isLoading = true)
            if (
                Common.isValidString(email.trim()) &&
                Common.isValidPassword(password.trim()) &&
                Common.isValidName(userName.value.trim()) &&
                Common.isValidStatus(status.value)
            ) {
                loginPresenter.signUp(email.trim(), password).addOnSuccessListener {
                    try {
                        val empleado = Empleado(
                            it.user!!.uid,
                            userName.value.trim(),
                            it.user!!.email!!,
                            status.value,
                        )
                        loginPresenter.createUserInDb(empleado).addOnSuccessListener {
                            state.value = state.value.copy(isSuccess = true)
                        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                            state.value = state.value.copy(isError = exception.message)
                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        state.value = state.value.copy(isError = e.message)
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    state.value = state.value.copy(isLoading = false)
                    state.value = state.value.copy(isError = it.message)
                }
            } else {
                state.value = state.value.copy(isLoading = false)
                state.value = state.value.copy(isError = "Rellena bien los campos")
            }


    }
}

fun dismiss() {
    state.value = state.value.copy(isError = null)
}
```

And here the calls:

```
override suspend fun signUp(email: String, password: String): Task<AuthResult> {
    return mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}

override  fun createUserInDb(user: Empleado): Task<Void> {
    return usersRef.child(user.uid!!).setValue(user.toMap())
}
```

First of all, the collection is: "employees"
and the document fields are:
.uid
.userName
.e-mail
.status

What I want to do is the following;

If there is no document in the "employees" collection;
The status field of the document to be inserted takes a value of 38. But if a document already exists in the collection, it takes the value of 1

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'there is no document in the "employees" collection'? Do you mean the `status` value depends on whether the `employees` node exists?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @. Besides that, since you're using Jetpack Compose, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) and this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) will help.